# Change color in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In My aaplication is Fragment with some LinearLayout (for example id is LL1). How can I change LL1 background color?
I want to do it by sharedpreferences (have two value: alpha and color) in OnCreate in Fragment.java:

```
SharedPreferences pref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
getView().findViewById(R.id.LL1).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(pref.getString(TRANSP_KEY, "#CC") + pref.getString(FCOLOR_KEY, "5556FF")));
```

There are not errors but when I try to start application:

```
Unfortunately application has stopped
```

I tried:

```
LinearLayout LL= (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.LL1);
LL.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

but there is the same problem

Probably setbackground doesn't work, if it is removed application works but has default colors (from xml file).

What am I doing wrong?

fragment.java:

```
package com.hgyghyfghyu.apkana40;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import static com.hgyghyfghyu.apkana40.AppData.FCOLOR_KEY;
import static com.hgyghyfghyu.apkana40.AppData.TRANSP_KEY;
import static com.hgyghyfghyu.apkana40.AppData.prefdata;
import static com.hgyghyfghyu.apkana40.UserData.editor;
import static com.hgyghyfghyu.apkana40.UserData.pref;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class TrainerMenu extends Fragment {


    public TrainerMenu() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        SharedPreferences pref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        LinearLayout imageView = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.trainermenutrainersbtn);
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
       // getView().findViewById(R.id.trainermenuadbtn).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(pref.getString(TRANSP_KEY, "#CC") + pref.getString(FCOLOR_KEY, "33777F")));

        //getView().findViewById(R.id.trainermenusettingsbtn).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(pref.getString(TRANSP_KEY, "#CC") + pref.getString(FCOLOR_KEY, "5556FF")));
       // getView().findViewById(R.id.trainermenuinfobtn).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(pref.getString(TRANSP_KEY, "#CC") + pref.getString(FCOLOR_KEY, "5556FF")));
        //getView().findViewById(R.id.trainermenugroupsbtn).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(pref.getString(TRANSP_KEY, "#CC") + pref.getString(FCOLOR_KEY, "5556FF")));


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trainer_menu, container, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: There should be errors is you see your app has stopped.

Comment: Where can i check it? debug is successful

Comment: Going solely from your code without a stack trace, I can only suggest you (i) check to make sure `LL` is not `null` before calling `setBackgroundColor()` on it and (ii) make sure you are calling `getView()` after `onCreateView()` *Edit:* Actually, point (ii) may well be your problem, as you say you're trying to run the above code in `onCreate()`...at this point, `getView()` will return `null`

Comment: To be honest I don't know how can i check that LL is not null, i edited my post and put there fragment file

Comment: `if (LL != null)`?? Anyways, I pretty sure my answer solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

> I want to do it in OnCreate in Fragment:

Well, you can't. `getView()` will return a null view inside `onCreate` because the View hasn't been created.

Please move the code to `onCreateView` after inflating the layout XML for your Fragment and use `findViewById` on the View that was inflated instead of using `getView()`

In code

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trainer_menu, container, false);
v.findViewById... 
return v;
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the documentation for the `getView()` method:

> `public View getView ()`
>
> Get the root view for the fragment's layout (the one returned by
>   `onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)`), if provided.
>
> Returns View  The fragment's root view, or null if it has no layout.

So, it wont work if you try to access your Fragment's layout with `getView()` before `onCreateView()` :). The following is one way of approaching this as `onViewCreated()` is called immediately after `onCreateView()`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trainer_menu, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    SharedPreferences pref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    LinearLayout imageView = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.trainermenutrainersbtn);
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```